# How to make NSTextView balance delimiters with a double-click?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nstextview

It's common to have a text editor for code or other structured content that balances delimiters of some sort; when you double click on a { it selects to the matching }, or similarly for ( ) pairs, [ ] pairs, etc.  How can I implement this behavior in `NSTextView` in Cocoa/Obj-C?

(I will be posting an answer momentarily, since I found nothing on SO about this and spent today implementing a solution.  Better answers are welcome.)

ADDENDUM:

This is not the same as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32408868/how-to-detect-double-click-in-nstextfield), which is about `NSTextField` and is primarily concerned with `NSTextField` and field editor issues.  **If** that question is solved by substituting a custom `NSTextView` subclass into the field editor, then that custom subclass could use the solution given here, of course; but there might be many other ways to solve the problem for `NSTextField`, and substituting a custom `NSTextView` subclass into the field editor is not obviously the right solution to that problem, and in any case a programmer concerned with delimiter balancing in `NSTextView` (which is presumably the more common problem) could care less about all of those `NSTextField` and field editor issues.  So that is a different question – although I will add a link from that question to this one, as one possible direction it could go.

This is also not the same as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22017233/nstextview-customizing-double-click-selection), which is really about changing the definition of a "word" in `NSTextView` when a double-click occurs.  As per [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/TextFonts/Conceptual/CocoaTextArchitecture/TextEditing/TextEditing.html), these are different problems with different solutions; for delimiter-balancing (this question) Apple specifically recommends the use of `NSTextView`'s `selectionRangeForProposedRange:granularity:` method, whereas for changing the definition of a word (that question) Apple specifically states that the `selectionRangeForProposedRange:granularity:` method should **not** be used.

Comment: You also posted an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32671117/1312143) to another duplicate question, so I'm not sure why you're posting this.

Comment: @KenThomases, these are not duplicates.  Please look more carefully.  The question you have marked as a duplicate of this one is about NSTextField, not NSTextView, and is primarily concerned with dealing with field editor issues (as usual with NSTextField).  That is a different class with different issues.  Look at the answer posted below, which uses selectionRangeForProposedRange:granularity: as specifically recommended by Apple for NSTextView.  The NSTextField question cannot use that (at least not directly), since that is not an NSTextField method.

Comment: The other question that you mention in your comment above as a duplicate is also not a duplicate.  That other question is about customizing double-click selection to obey different word boundaries; to treat a period as a word delimiter in all cases, specifically.  As per Apple's documentation, as reviewed carefully in both answers, that is a different problem requiring a different solution; Apple states that selectionRangeForProposedRange:granularity: should specifically **not** be used to solve that problem (but should be used for delimiter-balancing).

Comment: @KenThomases I have edited the question to make these distinctions more clear.  If you agree, then we can probably delete all these comments; I'm not sure what the etiquette is regarding that on SO.

Comment: I've reopened it. I'm not sure I agree it's really all that different than the first one and, despite the documentation you linked, it doesn't seem to me that `-selectionRangeForProposedRange:granularity:` is appropriate for this task, given the gymnastics you have to go through to figure out if it's called for a double-click. But, whatever.

Comment: Most of the gymnastics are really just an abundance of caution.  The use of `inEligibleDoubleClick` and the override of `mouseDown:` in my answer could both be removed entirely and I think it would still work.  It would just be less robust, because it would be making stronger assumptions about how `NSTextView` click handling works, and it would not fail as gracefully if those assumptions were false.  I agree that `selectionRangeForProposedRange:granularity:` is maybe not the best-designed API that Apple has ever produced; but I think it is clearly the best tool for the job nevertheless.

Answer (score 1):

In their Cocoa Text Architecture Guide (https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/TextFonts/Conceptual/CocoaTextArchitecture/TextEditing/TextEditing.html), Apple suggests subclassing `NSTextView` and overriding `selectionRangeForProposedRange:granularity:` to achieve this sort of thing; they even say "For example, in a code editor you can provide a delegate that extends a double click on a brace or parenthesis character to its matching delimiter."  However, it is not immediately clear how to achieve this, since you want the delimiter match to happen only at after a simple double-click on a delimiter, not after a double-click-drag or even a double-click-hold-release.

The best solution I could come up with involves overriding `mouseDown:` as well, and doing a little bookkeeping about the state of affairs.  Maybe there is a simpler way.  I've left out the core part of the code where the delimiter match actually gets calculated; that will depend on what delimiters you're matching, what syntactical complexities (strings, comments) might exist, and so forth.  In my code I actually call a tokenizer to get a token stream, and I use that to find the matching delimiter.  YMMV.  So, here's what I've got:

In your `NSTextView` subclass interface (or class extension, better yet):

```
// these are used in selectionRangeForProposedRange:granularity:
// to balance delimiters properly
BOOL inEligibleDoubleClick;
NSTimeInterval doubleDownTime;
```

In your `NSTextView` subclass implementation:

```
- (void)mouseDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent
{
    // Start out willing to work with a double-click for delimiter-balancing;
    // see selectionRangeForProposedRange:proposedCharRange granularity: below
    inEligibleDoubleClick = YES;

    [super mouseDown:theEvent];
}

- (NSRange)selectionRangeForProposedRange:(NSRange)proposedCharRange
    granularity:(NSSelectionGranularity)granularity
{
    if ((granularity == NSSelectByWord) && inEligibleDoubleClick)
    {
        // The proposed range has to be zero-length to qualify
        if (proposedCharRange.length == 0)
        {
            NSEvent *event = [NSApp currentEvent];
            NSEventType eventType = [event type];
            NSTimeInterval eventTime = [event timestamp];

            if (eventType == NSLeftMouseDown)
            {
                // This is the mouseDown of the double-click; we do not want
                // to modify the selection here, just log the time
                doubleDownTime = eventTime;
            }
            else if (eventType == NSLeftMouseUp)
            {
                // After the double-click interval since the second mouseDown,
                // the mouseUp is no longer eligible
                if (eventTime - doubleDownTime <= [NSEvent doubleClickInterval])
                {
                    NSString *scriptString = [[self textStorage] string];

                    ...insert delimiter-finding code here...
                    ...return the matched range, or NSBeep()...
                }
                else
                {
                    inEligibleDoubleClick = false;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                inEligibleDoubleClick = false;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            inEligibleDoubleClick = false;
        }
    }

    return [super selectionRangeForProposedRange:proposedCharRange
        granularity:granularity];
}
```

It's a little fragile, because it relies on `NSTextView`'s tracking working in a particular way and calling out to `selectionRangeForProposedRange:granularity:` in a particular way, but the assumptions are not large; I imagine it's pretty robust.